# Compound assignment E1 op= E2 is not equivalent to E1 = E1 op E2

Tags: c++, operators, variable-assignment

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_compound_assignment) says:

> the behavior of every builtin compound-assignment expression `E1 op= E2` (where `E1` is a modifiable lvalue expression and `E2` is an rvalue expression or a braced-init-list (since C++11)) is exactly the same as the behavior of the expression `E1 = E1 op E2`, except that the expression `E1` is evaluated only once and that it behaves as a single operation with respect to indeterminately-sequenced function calls (e.g. in `f(a += b, g())`, the `+=` is either not started at all or is completed as seen from inside `g()`)."

I want to know if this explanation is wrong (insufficient) or I'm understanding something incorrectly.

I understand there's inherent difference between `E1 = E1 + E2` and `E1 += E2`,
which is explained [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134118/why-are-shortcuts-like-x-y-considered-good-practice):

```
#include<iostream>
int main() {

    int x;

    x = 1;
    x += (-1) ? 2 : 2; 
    std::cout << x << std::endl; //prints 3

    x = 1;
    x = x + (-1) ? 2 : 2;
    std::cout << x << std::endl; //prints 2

    x = 2;
    x += (-2) == 0;
    std::cout << x << std::endl; //prints 2

    x = 2;
    x = x + (-2) == 0; // prints 1

}
```

My guess is `E1 op= E2` has the following behavior:

- Evaluate `E1` and `E2` (unsure about the order) and assign result of operation between two evaluation to `E1`, which is `(E1) = (E1) op (E2)`.

So would a better explanation for compound assignment operation's behavior be
`(E1) = (E1) op (E2)`? (or `E1 = E1 op (E2)`, because `E1` only can have operator of higher precedence than assignment operator and lower precedence than op operator, without parentheses, if `E1 op (E2)` wants to produce different result from `(E1) op (E2)`. Such operator whose result is a modifiable lvalue doesn't exist.)

Comment: I think that explanation is meant to be conceptual and not syntactic; they are describing the meaning, not providing a macro.

Comment: @ScottHunter yep probably, still bit confusing.

Comment: Only if you are very literal-minded :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That quote from cppreference comes directly from the C++ Standard:

> #### [`[expr.ass]/6`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#6)
>
> The behavior of an expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = E1 op E2` except that `E1` is evaluated only once.
>   Such expressions are deprecated if `E1` has *volatile-qualified* type; see `[depr.volatile.type]`.
>   For `+=` and `-=`, `E1` shall either have arithmetic type or be a pointer to a possibly cv-qualified completely-defined object type.
>   In all other cases, `E1` shall have arithmetic type.

In this context, [the term *expression* has already been defined](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prop) and `E1 op= E2` being equivalent to `E1 = E1 op E2` clearly doesn't mean the expressions are equivalent in their textual representation, but in their resolution (type, value and side-effects).

> [A] better explanation for compound assignment operation's behavior could be (E1) = (E1) op (E2)?

I only can express my opinion: I *think* the cpprederence page is right to quote the Standard here, but a note could be added to make sure readers do not get it wrong.

Comment: So I guess when standard is referring to expressions as E1, E2, .. it's assuming its' evaluations are done already.

Answer (score 4):

This is about operator precedence. `+` has higher precedence than the ternary conditional (and also `==`). So this:

```
x = x + (-1) ? 2 : 2;
```

Is evaluated like this:

```
x = (x + (-1)) ? 2 : 2;
```

That's why you get `2` instead of `3`. Same with the other sample:

```
x = x + (-2) == 0
```

is evaluated as

```
x = (x + (-2)) == 0 // (x + (-2)) is 0, 0 == 0 is 1
```

---

So taking the first example:

```
x = x + (-1) ? 2 : 2;
```

Here `A` is `x` and `B` is `(x + (-1) ? 2 : 2)` (`x` plus the result of the ternary operation)

Here, however

```
x += (-1) ? 2 : 2;
```

`A` is `x` and `B` is just the result of the ternary operation. What `A` and `B` are changed due to `+=` having a lower precedence than `=`. So the statement about E1 = E1 + E2 and E1 += E2 being the same is correct, but it doesn't mean that transforming `E1 = E1 + E2` to `E1 += E2` will never change what `E1` and `E2` mean. Which seems a bit misleading.

Comment: You might have overlooked the question. "so better explanation for compound assignment operation's behavior could be (E1) = (E1) op (E2)?"

Comment: yep, so my question is: is explanation provided by cppreference which states A op= B behaves equivalently to A = A op B is incorrect? (or at least ambiguous)

Comment: It's not incorrect, it's just that due to what happens with operator precedence, the A and B aren't the same anymore. I'll edit my post to try to explain it in better detail.

Comment: @Pleasure `A = A op B` would be `x = x + ((-1) ? 2 : 2);` you are asking why is `A op= B` not the same as `A = A op C` because the expressions in your example are made from the same tokens but due to associativity and operator precendence the same tokens in a different context can be a different expression

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ Standard (8.5.18 Assignment and compound assignment operators)

> 7 The behavior of an expression of the form E1 op = E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = E1 op E2 except that E1 is evaluated only once. In += and -=,
>   E1 shall either have arithmetic type or be a pointer to a possibly
>   cv-qualified completely-defined object type. In all other cases, E1
>   shall have arithmetic type.

And (8.5.6 Additive operators)

> 1 **The additive operators + and - group left-to-right.** The usual
>   arithmetic conversions (8.3) are performed for operands of arithmetic
>   or enumeration type.

These expression statements

```
x = x + (-1) ? 2 : 2;
x += (-2) == 0;
x = x + (-2) == 0;
```

are equivalent to

```
x = ( x - 1 ) ? 2 : 2;
x += ( -2 == 0 );
x = ( ( x - 2 ) == 0 );
```

Comment: why are you mentioning additive operators' associativity? If it's because of (-2) it's unary minus operator.

Comment: @Pleasure Because you wrote that you did not know the order of evaluations in the assignment expression.