# XORing two variables and adding the result to a third varibable works with operator += but not with operators = and + used in combination

Tags: c++, operators, bitwise-operators, operator-precedence

I have some code that performs a bitwise XOR operation (`^`) on two variables and adds the result to a third variable.

Turns out that the following two statements produce different results:

```cpp
checksum += digit ^ (2 * checksum);               //correct result
checksum = checksum + digit ^ (2 * checksum);     //incorrect result
```

Why is that so?
(**Edit: I changed the question to specifically target the issue that was causing problems with my program.**)

Comment: The 2 statements are not equivalent due to Operator Precedence see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence  `+` is higher than `^`

Comment: This is funny, we were discussing something similar a few hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727204/compound-assignment-e1-op-e2-is-not-equivalent-to-e1-e1-op-e2/57727405#57727405

Comment: Does the following line gives you the right answer: `checksum = checksum + (digit ^ (2 * checksum));`?

Comment: @KorelK Yep, that worked! And now it makes sense! The bitwise XOR operator has lower precedence than the addition operator. That's why I was getting the wierd result, right?

Comment: At first look, it seems to be quite a weak checksum. Is this for a pet project or to actually protect anything ?

Comment: @CripplingDepression right :)

Comment: It doesn't actually protect anything. It's just an exercise on reverse engineering. I translated an x86 binary into the equivalent C++ code for better understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This expression

```
checksum = checksum + digit ^ (2 * checksum);
```

is evaluated like

```
checksum = ( checksum + digit ) ^ (2 * checksum);
```

because the Bitwise exclusive OR operator `^` has a lower priority than the additive operator +.

This expression

```
checksum += digit ^ (2 * checksum);
```

is evaluated like

```
checksum = ( checksum ) + ( digit ^ (2 * checksum) );
```

That is in this compound assignment operator

```
checksum += digit ^ (2 * checksum);
```

the expression `digit ^ (2 * checksum)` is evaluated and added to the value of `checksum`.

From the C++ 17 Standard (8.5.18 Assignment and compound assignment operators)

> 7 The behavior of an expression of the form E1 op = E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = E1 op E2 except that E1 is evaluated only once. In += and -=,
>   E1 shall either have arithmetic type or be a pointer to a possibly
>   cv-qualified completely-defined object type. In all other cases, E1
>   shall have arithmetic type.

So there are two expressions `E1` and `E2` that are evaluated and then the binary operator `op` is applied to them.

Comment: Explaining *why* and linking to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence would improve your answer (IMHO).